# why does Carbon::parse('2023-11-30')->diffInMonths(Carbon::parse('2023-10-01'), false); return 1 instead of 2?

Tags: php, php-carbon

When I try to use carbon diffInMonths() it gives me values less 1, why is that?

```php
$months = Carbon::parse('2023-11-30')->diffInMonths(Carbon::parse('2023-10-01'), false);

//$months = 1 instead of 2
```

What am I doing wrong?

I am manually adding 1 after results which is dangerous.

Comment: It gets the difference in months rounded down. See the documentation.

Comment: It's 1 month, 29 days. Why would it be 2 months?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want rounded diff:

```
$months = round(Carbon::parse('2023-11-30')->floatDiffInMonths(Carbon::parse('2023-10-01'), false));
```

Comment: In my case `ceil()` is the best option. But `floatDiffInMonths()` works like a charm. Thankyou

Comment: This solution gives me -2 (float) as a result in a test. The result is 2 with true as 2nd parameter.
However, the code also returns the same results with 2023-11-16 as the first date. Have strong doubts whether this should be the solution that the questioner was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The **diffInMonths()** method in **Carbon** calculates the difference between two dates in months. However, it rounds down the result to the nearest whole number. In your example, the difference between **'2023-11-30'** and **'2023-10-01'** is 1 month and 29 days, which is less than 2 full months. Therefore, the method returns 1.

To round up the result of Carbon's **diffInMonths()** when there's a partial month:

- Calculate the difference in months using diffInMonths().
- Check if there are remaining days after subtracting the month difference.
- Add 1 to the result if there are any remaining days.

```
    $date1 = Carbon::parse('2023-11-30');
    $date2 = Carbon::parse('2023-10-01');
        
    $months = $date1->diffInMonths($date2, false);
        
    // Check if there are remaining days after calculating the month difference
    if ($date1->copy()->subMonths($months)->gt($date2)) {
        $months++;
    }  
    
    echo $months; // Output: 2
```

This will calculate the difference in months and add 1 if there are any remaining days after subtracting the month difference. This way, you will get 2 as the result in your example, and you won't need to manually add 1 to the result.

Comment: It's a work around.